# Radium with useState makes Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, radium

I use Radium and it works, but when I add useState I get this error:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...

Can I repair it without changing function to class?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Radium, {StyleRoot} from 'radium';

const App = ()=>{
  const [tab, updateTab] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

  return (
    <StyleRoot>
      <div className='App'>

      </div>
    </StyleRoot>
  )
};

export default Radium(App);
```

Comment: The error basically means your violating the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I repair it without changing function to class?

Yes. 
To make this work, [extract a component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components) to put your hooks.

```
const Root = () => {
  const [tab, updateTab] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  return <div className="App" />;
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StyleRoot>
      <Root />
    </StyleRoot>
  )
};

export default Radium(App);
```

Comment: So every component which contains useState I should wrap new function.
But why it doesn't work without it?

Comment: If it's a class component, then follow the [2 rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).